# Python googletrans returns only one word

Tags: python, tkinter, google-translate, googletrans

I make a translator app using tkinter and googletrans

but when i run it, the googletrans only return 1 word
here is my full code (main.py)

```
#Importing modules
from tkinter import *
from googletrans import Translator

##Main Script
#Main Window
Window = Tk()
Window.geometry("400x700")
Window.resizable(False, False)
Window.configure(bg="#e1f4f3")

#Defs
def translate():
    ans = inp.get(1.0)
    trans = Translator()
    t = trans.translate(
        ans, src="id", dest="en"
    )

    trans_txt.config(state="normal")
    trans_txt.delete(END, "end")
    trans_txt.insert(END, t.text)
    trans_txt.config(state="normal")

#Widgets
#main frame
main = Frame(Window, width=300, height=500, bg="#00d1ff", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

#entries
#input user
inp = Text(main, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, font=("Gotham Book", 20))
inp.pack_propagate(0)

#translate btn
translate_btn = Button(main, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, font=("Gotham Book", 20), text="Translate", command=translate)
translate_btn.configure(highlightbackground="light blue")
translate_btn.pack_propagate(0)

#translation
trans_txt = Text(main, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, font=("Gotham Book", 20))
trans_txt.config(state="disabled")
trans_txt.pack_propagate(0)

#Packs
main.place(anchor="c", rely=.5, relx=.5)

inp.place(x=150, anchor="c", y=100, height=90, width=250)
translate_btn.place(x=150, anchor="c", y=250)
trans_txt.place(x=150, anchor="c", y=400, height=90, width=250)

#Window.mainloop()
Window.mainloop()
```

the main.py returns

```
H
```

when i type "Hai".
in the inp widget

but in the other code file (trans_test.py)
it returns the right translated word
here is trans_test.py full code

```
#Importing modules
from googletrans import Translator

#trans()
def trans(text):
    trans = Translator()
    t = trans.translate(
        text, src="id", dest="en"
    )
    return t.text

#test
print(trans("Hai"))
```

the trans_test.py returns

```
Hi
```

Thank you if someone answer this :)

Comment: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you getting only `h` is that your `translate` function is trying to translate `h` which is `h`. At line `ans = inp.get(1.0)`, you are just getting the character at row 1 and col 0 aka `1.0`, you need to get the complete text which can be done by doing `ans = inp.get(1.0, 'end')`.

Also, I want to address `trans_txt.delete(END, "end")` if you are trying to delete the text completely then you need to delete from *staring index* to the *end index* so it should be.

```
trans_txt.delete(1.0, "end")
```

Both `END` or `"end"`  are the same values don't get confused.

Also if you are trying to make the 2nd Text widget a read-only Text then you just need to disable the state after inserting.

*Improved `translate` function*

```py
def translate():
    ans = inp.get(1.0, 'end')
    trans = Translator()
    t = trans.translate(ans, src="id", dest="en")
    trans_txt.config(state="normal")
    trans_txt.delete(1.0, "end")
    trans_txt.insert(END, t.text)
    trans_txt.config(state="disabled")
```